# WiFi keeps dropping out on Lubuntu latest build

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, realtek

i am relatively new to linux and I installed Lubuntu due to space restrictions on a Lenovo IdeaPad 100s with a Realtek RTL8723BS integrated wifi adaptor. I have installed build essentials and upgraded to the latest build but the WiFi keeps dropping out. Can someone please help.

Thanks,

Stuart

Comment: which release please. `lsb_release -rd`

Comment: What do you mean by *latest* build?   Are you talking about a *daily*? in which case which one.  Lubuntu *hirsute* is not currently on-topic here as it hasn't been released, and the *focal* daily offers little over a released version; so why did you get a *testing* build? and not a released system?  Please clarify which you are asking about.  Specific details are required, as you mention building, thus kernel details are needed (the ISO used to install controls this; which did you use? what are you running? etc)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this might help https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2249936.

It's written for Ubuntu (not Lubuntu) so I am unsure if it is the answer you are looking for but it may help.

It may not be possible without working on the driver yourself as the documentation says that the 8273BE version of the chip (especially for HP and Lenovo users) may have ongoing issues even after a fix stated here "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsRealTek"